# how to use tum_simulator in kinetic ros?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I have installed kinetic ROS in my system. But I am unable to get any autopilot simulator  like tum_simulator for a.r. drone to control it with the laptop keyboard. The tum_simulator is for **indigo** ROS which is not running with the kinetic ROS.
Is there any library which makes me able to use the tum_simulator using kinetic ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302029/how-to-use-tum_simulator-in-kinetic-ros?/) by [tanmay](https://answers.ros.org/users/37250/tanmay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `tum_simulator` package has not been actively maintained for a long time. Thankfully someone has already ported it to work on Kinetic. Here's the [repository](https://github.com/angelsantamaria/tum_simulator/tree/kinetic). You will need to clone and checkout the `kinetic` branch.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2018-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tanmay](https://answers.ros.org/users/37250/tanmay/) on 2018-09-06**:
Thank you Sir for your reply. The above said repository works fine with the kinetic ros.